# Aborting installation. npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

```
Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

Try a lot from Yarn and NPM to clear the cache update node and Yarn and NPM version, but still getting the same error. What is the solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different network: For example, you can try connecting to a different Wi-Fi network or using a mobile hotspot.

Hope this should help you.This Works For me.